# how to reduce gap between Title(Appoitment) and Icon Image(Appointment) in this persistent navigation bar

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
 PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset(
          "assets/homeScreenImages/appointment_active.png",
        ),
        inactiveIcon: Image.asset(
          "assets/homeScreenImages/appointment_unactive.png",
        ),
        title: ("Appointment"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.orange[700],
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try with the icon size

```
icon: Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
   child: Icon(  Image.asset(
                  "assets/homeScreenImages/appointment_active.png"),                
   ),
),
```

Comment: it's work with icon....but it doesn't work when we give image in icon

Comment: because your png image take more space

Comment: Yes exactly....but is there any solution of my problem when I am using image.....

Comment: try with `aligment` center or bottomCenter. If it's not workable  otherwise you will go for svg image.

Comment: It's not working [alignment: Alignment.center,]

Comment: little bit try with [alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,]

Comment: updated my answer please one more try and also try with [EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),]